# Infinitude of primes using series introduced in Connes' paper on Wilson's theorem

Tags: number-theory, analysis, summation, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Consider the following sum:

$$S(p)=\sum_{n=2}^p\sin^2\left(\frac{π\Gamma(n)}{2n}\right)$$

The summand is zero for non-primes, and finite and non-decreasing for primes

For more details see the key paper:
[Connes' paper on Wilson's theorem](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.02832&ved=2ahUKEwjd4Y7csPznAhU4H7cAHe48APoQFjAAegQIBhAC&usg=AOvVaw1sYdzCHfHtkkmaO6ClRpfz)

> Question :

> Is there any way we can prove infinitude of primes using above series ?

I tried to attack this problem in my previous questions . I just posted this separately new question (without stating any of my work) to start fresh and expecting new methods and views from users .

Any suggestions and comments are welcome .

> Possible unified Applications: We can apply it to other primes of special forms whose Infinitude is unknown. (as Γ is nicely analytic):

$$S_2(p)=\sum_{n=2}^p\sin^2\left(\frac{π\Gamma(n)}{2n}\right)\sin^2\left(\frac{π\Gamma(n+2)}{2(n+2)}\right)$$

See also for details :[Towards a new proof of infinitude of primes ( with possible unified application to other primes of special forms whose Infinitude is unknown):](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3570663/702232)

Comment: So essentially you'd like to show that $S(p)\rightarrow\infty$? for $p\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: @AlexR. Yes,sir

Comment: Not that this isn't an extremely interesting idea, but I honestly don't see a good way to go forward in general unless one pulls out some extremely difficult mathematics. For example, there really isn't that much difference between $S_2(p)$ and $S_3(p)$ but we would expect the first sum to go to infinity while the second sum converges after the first few terms. However, from an analytic standpoint, I couldn't tell you what the difference is between the series (just that there must be one).

Comment: @QC_QAOA seeing the wide range of applications, it's worth to pull that extremely difficult mathematics.

Comment: Got a downvotes! Please explain what's wrong