# Comparison of integrals with a function (at least numerically):

Tags: real-analysis, integration, number-theory, numerical-methods, graphing-functions

Consider the following integral:

$$S(q)=\int_{x=2}^q\sin^2\left(\frac{π\Gamma(x)}{2x}\right)dx$$

And consider  functions :

$$R(q)=\frac{q}{\log(q)}$$

$$T(q)=\int_2^q\frac{1}{\log(x)}dx$$

I want to compare them with each other ( at least numerically for large interval of value  )

If graph for very large intervals (upto atleast $10^4$) possible please add ( please add all the graph in one axis system so I can compare them ).

(Due to wild oscillations of $S(q)$; I can't deal with it )( Mathematica doesn't seem to help with large values ).

(Does numerics suggests  $S(q) \sim R(q)$ or $T(q)$? ).

See ; Related : [Towards a new proof of infinitude of primes ( with possible unified application to other primes of special forms whose Infinitude is unknown):](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3570663/702232)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want a graph of those three function with $2\le q\le10^4$?

Comment: @Jan  yes! That's what I want

Comment: Why a close vote !?

Comment: I already mentioned the link where all the details are mentioned , why to repeat again ?