# On a growth condition satisfied by given functional :

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

Consider the following function :

$$f(x) = \sin^2(\frac{π\Gamma(x)}{2x})$$

Is following growth condition true ?:

> > $$\int_0^\infty \frac{f(x + iy) − f(x − iy)}{e^{2πy}-1} dy=o\left(\int_2^x f(t) dt\right) $$ ?

If yes , how to achieve it?

One can also ask for the following :

> > $$\int_0^\infty \frac{f(x + iy) − f(x − iy)}{e^{2πy}-1} dy=o(g_1(x))=O(g_2(x)) $$

As $x \to \infty$.

> > what are some possible candidates for $g_1(x)$ and $g_2(x)$ ?Also can we find $g_1(x)$ and $g_2(x)$ for which bounds are sharp?

See [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3570663/702232) for more details

Accurate (upto 4 decimals) values of functional upto $x=5$:

[image: accurate (upto 4 decimals) values of functional upto x=5][image: values of functional upto x=5]

> > Important: Any computational analysis expert can help me to compute them for larger $x$ upto 100 or 1000 or provide me with graph for large $x$ Answers and comments from them are welcome

Comment: What do you get from Stirling (the sum over poles of $\Gamma'/\Gamma$ is up to a $\log(z)$ term a power series in $z^{-1}$ which gives very good approximations of $\sin(\Gamma)$)

Comment: Please avoid making several edits.

Comment: Please explain the downvotes!